# Counting responses of all columns in R

Tags: r, count, multiple-columns

In R I have a dataset with over 400 columns (survey questions) and 5000 rows (participants)

[image]

I would like to count how many responses were recorded against each question, i.e. for questions 1 to 3 there are 4 responses and then for Q3a and Q4 there are 2 responses.

Is there a way to count this and produce a table with the counts of each column without specifically naming all 400 columns?

Most responses are in numbers however some are also in text form.

Learning R and so far none of the solutions I've seen are working for this

Comment: `library(tidyverse); df |> pivot_longer(everything()) |> summarize(responses = n_distinct(value), .by = name)`

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for the response, I received an error message saying that an integer column could not be combined with a character column

Comment: Could share some of your data so we can have a see? Assuming the whole table follows a similar pattern we only need a small subset. Try `dput(dtf[1:6, 1:4])`. This will select the first six rows and first four columns of `dtf` (your data), and output it in a form that is convenient for R to read. Also, try and mock up how you'd like the output to be.

Comment: For mixed data format columns, one approach could be to coerce all to character and count from there -- eg replace the `pivot_longer` line with `pivot_longer(everything(), values_transform = as.character) |>`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `colSums` to create a logical vector (ie `TRUE`/`FALSE`) if they meet your conditions - in R, logicals are treated mathematically as 1 (TRUE) and 0 (FALSE). So using `colSums` will sum up the counts of what you need.

From you image, it looks like you have two types of columns. Primary answers have numerical responses, and some questions have free text. So we need to create another logical vector, `x`, to separate these out:

```
x <- vapply(df, is.numeric, logical(1L))

x[x] <- colSums(df[x] != 0)
x[!x] <- colSums(!is.na(df[!x])) 

# Q1  Q2  Q3 Q3a  Q4 
#  4   4   4   2   2
```

Data

```
df <- data.frame(Q1 = c(1,2,1,1),
                 Q2 = c(1,1,1,2),
                 Q3 = c(7,5,1,4),
                 Q3a = c("other", "shop", NA, NA),
                 Q4 = c(1,0,2,0))
```

Note if you had true blanks in your data (not `NA` as above - i.e. `Q3a = c("other", "shop", "", "")`), then you could replace the last line with `x[!x] <- colSums(df[!x] != "")`

If this sample data isn't representative of your real data, please edit your question to include reproducible data.